# How can I access an emulator running on a computer from an emulator running on other computer on same lan using Socket and ServerSocket?

Tags: android, sockets, connection, lan, serversocket

There will be two emulators running. One of them is running on computer A. The other one is running on computer B.
A and B are on same lan.
I want to use Socket, ServerSocket classes.
How can possible these two emulators see each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the " Interconnecting Emulator Instances " part here
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

> **Interconnecting Emulator Instances**
>   
> To allow one emulator instance to communicate with another, you must set up the necessary network redirection as illustrated below.
>   Assume that your environment is
>
> A is you development machine
>
> B is your first emulator instance, running on A
>
> C is your second emulator instance, also running on A
>
> and you want to run a server on B, to which C will connect, here is how you could set it up:
>
> 1. Set up the server on B, listening to 10.0.2.15:
>
>    1. On B's console, set up a redirection from A:localhost: to B:10.0.2.15:
> 2. On C, have the client connect to 10.0.2.2:
>
> For example, if you wanted to run an HTTP server, you can select  as 80 and  as 8080:
>
> B listens on 10.0.2.15:80
>
> On B's console, issue redir add tcp:8080:80
>
> C connects to 10.0.2.2:8080

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.